# what permissions are necessary to be able to create apex sharing rules for a record?

Tags: sharing, apex-managed-sharing, apex-sharing

I have a test user that has permission to a specific record but cannot create an apex managed sharing record for the given record. What additional permissions are necessary to be able to create a managed sharing record?

Error:

```
System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: Case__Share.RowCause
```

I don't receive any error when attempting to create the record via the same VF page as an admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user needs to have the 'Modify All Data' permission.

From the documentation

> Apex managed sharing provides developers with the
>   ability to support an application’s particular sharing requirements
>   programmatically through Apex or the SOAP API. This type of sharing is
>   similar to Force.com managed sharing. ***Only users with “Modify All
>   Data” permission can add or change Apex managed sharing on a record.***
>   Apex managed sharing is maintained across record owner changes.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm

Comment: It's worth noting that apex run in "system mode", i.e. without sharing, bypasses this restriction. You can use a without sharing class to keep your apex-managed sharing consistent.

Comment: great point. very true